# To compile Pandoc Table in Editor by selection

Tags: unix, text-editors, latex, text-editing, textmate

Pandoc table in Tex document based on this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245427/13173)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                       Arrythmia
- ------------------------      ----------------------------------     ----------
1 a sodium channel blocker      \underline{procainamide}               V

  b sodium channel blocker      (Lidocaine),                           V
                                Phenytoin 
                                % no effect on QRS                              

  c sodium channel blocker      propafenon                             SV

2 beta blockers                 propranolol, 
                                metoprolol, 
                                bisoprolol                             

3 K ch. blocker                 \underline{amiodarone}, (sotalol)      V, TA        

4 Slow CCB non DHP              verapamil, diltiazem                   SV 

5 digoxin                       digoxin                                SV
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Rate Control anti-arrhythmics.
```

which can be compiled by `pandoc -s something.md -o something.tex` in a separate file or by pasting the table into separate file, adding `\documentclass{article}; \usepackage{caption}; \usepackage{longtable}; \usepackage{booktabs}; \begin{document}` before it and after it `\end{document}`, and compiling by *pdflatex*. 
In Vim, you could simply run externally by `:<selection>![pandoc-cmd]`. 
However, currently, I am using editors such as Textmate and TexPad in OSX. 
Open to any other approaches too.

I do not want to have computer-language for tables in my document. 
This kind of feature as in terminal editors and vim would be awesome to get, as discussed for Vim and running Python there [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim/501698#501698). 
**How can you compile the pandoc table into external pdf-file by selection in some IDE text editor?**

### Textmate

Select table, select Text > Filter Through Command with New Document and run `pandoc -f markdown -t latex` to get a table in a new document. 
However, to pipe the output some script is still unknown if you can do it or not. 
So Textmate may not be sufficient. 
only `| script-to-add-head-and-tail text | pdflatex | open the pdf` is wanted.